# Troubleshooting Visual Studio 2019 Code Map errors

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, visual-studio-2019, class-diagram, code-map

I have a Visual Studio 2019 (16.5.4) solution with about 10 .Net Core projects, some are `netcoreapp3.1` others are `netstandard2.0`. Some have project references to the other projects, most have NuPkg dependencies.

If I attempt to generate a Code Map from the solution, most projects render as expected in in the map, while 2 projects render with a red X next to the assembly name with no ability to expand the node.

[image: Error Node]

I have no idea what the Code Map doesn't like. At first I thought it was the `netcoreapp3.1` but I tried adding a new project of that time and it renders fine.

---

EDIT:
After trying to create a simple project to reproduce the issue, i've narrowed it to the inclusion of this package reference:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.5" />
</ItemGroup>
```

So, there is something in this library that's causing the map to crash?

---

**Is there some log file or other telemetry that I can use to help troubleshoot this issue so I can revise the projects to generate a successful map?**

Thanks

-John

Comment: You can check the feedback link I gave in the answer and upvote it. The Microsoft team is counting how many people are affected by this problem and based on the vote to determine when to fix it.

Comment: The feedback link I gave was duplicated with another feedback I sent. You should pay attention to this: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1003585/code-map-comes-up-with-errors-when-install-azure-f.html

Answer (score 1):

I contacted the person responsible for VS Architecture Tools in the Microsoft product group.

In the end, it was determined that this was a problem to be fixed. I opened a feedback here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1003585/code-map-comes-up-with-errors-when-install-azure-f.html

Microsoft will gauge how many customers are affected by this and repair prioritize accordingly with this feedback. You can vote to this feedback.:)